# Calculating number of roads between two polylines in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, contour

[image]

I have a file that contains contour lines and want to know how the number of roads that are located between each set of contour lines.  How can I go about achieving this?

I provided an example where I have three roads between contour line 30 and contour line 40.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.se. Can you provide more detail on your problem? Please see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think an [Intersect Analysis](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00080000000p000000) would solve the problem. Point output would be fine (it will return a point for each point of intersection). This operation will give you all the fields common to each input layer. This way you can identify all the points with a contour value of 30 and count all the unique road names or go the other way and sum up all the unique contour values on any given road.